# Is this an acceptable algorithm for pedestrian motion that searches and mingles with "buddies" on its path to the goal?

Tags: simulation, netlogo, multi-agent

I'll put my pseudocode here first, please advise regarding its validity according to real-world pedestrian motion, and how I can improve it.

Premise: A turtle walk from its spawn point to the goal. On the way, it meets other turtles. Turtles of the same color will be treated as a "buddy" and will go near it, simulating a "friends-walking-down-the-street" scenario. Turtles of the same color with nearer distance has higher priority, e.g. friend A is nearer than friend B so I will approach friend A first.

Upon approaching the goal, the turtle goes back to its spawn point.

Pseudocode:

```
determine if i am already in the goal
if yes,
    determine if there are patches I can walk on
    set eyes on nearest patch I can walk on (for the goal path)
    if there is a friend nearby, approach friend
    if there is no friend nearby, continue walking the goal path
    if im already in the goal, respawn.
```

Advise for improvement please?

Answer (score 1):

The premise doesn't say anything about how returning to spawn point occurs so I will assume it is a one step action (ie you are not interested in those details). I see something more along the lines of

```
spawn loop: 
  spawn
  goal loop: 
    determine if turtle already reached goal
    if no,
      determine if there are patches I can walk on
      set eyes on nearest patch I can walk on (for the goal path)
      if there is a friend nearby, approach friend
      if there is no friend nearby, continue walking the goal path
    if yes, 
      setup so can respawn (return to spawn loc, etc)
      goal loop ends
```